# What's the easiest, most concise, way to prove this simple swapping of order of nested summation?

Tags: summation, summation-method

$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \, a_{nk} \ = \ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{n=1}^{k} \, a_{nk} $$

for $N \in \mathbb{N} < \infty$

Comment: i realize that this is a very pedantic question.

Comment: The equality doesn't hold (unless $a_{ij}=a_{ji}\,$), try $N=2$ for example.

Comment: It isn't true. But the following is true: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \, a_{nk} \ = \ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{n=k}^{N} \, a_{nk}$

Comment: okay, i am gonna have to think about this.  it seems to me that it **has** to be true.  but i got something mixed up.

Comment: thanks for the quick replies.

Comment: @grand_chat, can you put your comment into an answer and then spell out (in the answer) how your expression is true?

Comment: just want to acknowledge that the question as i posed it, has a false premise.  i could change it to have a true premise but i think it is more instructive to others that i leave it alone (and incorrect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to prove the identity
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \, a_{nk} \ = \ \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{n=k}^{N} \, a_{nk}
$$
is to introduce *indicator* notation. Use the expression $I(a \le b)$ to represent the value $1$ when $a\le b$ and value $0$ otherwise:

$$
I(a \le b) \triangleq \begin{cases}
1 \qquad & a \le b \\
\\
0 \qquad & a > b \\
\end{cases}
$$

Then
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} \, a_{nk}
\stackrel{(1)}=
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{k=1}^N \, a_{nk} \ I(k\le n)
\stackrel{(2)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}\, a_{nk} \ I(k\le n)
\stackrel{(3)}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N \sum\limits_{n=k}^{N}\, a_{nk}\,.
$$
In step (1) we multiply $a_{nk}$ by an indicator to allow the inner sum to range over all $k=1,\ldots,N$. Now both sums range from $1$ to $N$, so we can swap the order of summation, which is step (2). Step (3) then removes the indicator by absorbing it into the limits of the inner sum.

Comment: thank you, grand.

Comment: i believe the same reasoning exists for

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n} \, a_{nk} \ = \ \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} \, \sum\limits_{n=k}^{N} \, a_{nk} $$

does it not?

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson Yes, you are correct!

Comment: thanks, grand.  i am finding this very useful for [this problem involving summations with the binomial coefficient](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/36202/monotonic-symmetrical-soft-clipping-polynomial/36204#36204).  i realize that the math here is small potatoes, but as you can see that i posed the question wrongly, i am not taking any chances.

Answer (score 1):

Swapping the order of finite summations can't change the value; only for infinite sums does addition become non-commutative. However, you're not just swapping the *order*, you're swapping the *limits*. If you imagine arranging the elements in an $N \times N$ array, with the first index going from top to bottom, and the second going from left to right, then the LHS sums the bottom left triangle, while the RHS sums the top right (with the diagonal being included in both).

A similar thing happens if you do a double integral of $xy^2$. If you integrate $y$ from 0 to $x$, you get $\frac{x^4}3$. Integrating that from 0 to $t$ gives you $\frac{t^5}{15}$. If you instead integrated $x$ from 0 to $y$, you get $\frac{y^4}2$, and integrating that from 0 to $t$ gives you $\frac{t^5}{10}$.

Comment: my 62-year-old brain is still groking this.  i **was** trying to imagine this sum of elements of a triangular matrix.  but for some reason i thought i had the equation i displayed rather than the correction @grand_chat displays.

Comment: i am still having trouble.  it seems to me (in my expression) it's the same half of the square array.

Answer (score 1):

It is sometimes useful to represent the index range of summation as *inequality chain*. This way the region of validity can be often seen easily.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{k=1}^na_{nk}=\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq k\leq n\leq N}}a_{nk}=\sum_{k=1}^N\sum_{n=k}^Na_{nk}
> \end{align*}

Comment: whoa!  that's a scary notation!  being a lowly electrical engineer i try to stay away from novel notation, even if it's a little more compact.  but now, if i ever see that, i will know what it is.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: The nice aspect with this notation is that we can directly deduce for the inner sums that $1\leq k\leq n$ at the left-hand side as well as $n\leq k\leq N$ at the right-hand side. The rather simple interpretation of this and a far more general index range is given in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1877144)*.

Comment: kewl.  i like Knuth.  i first learned from some Knuth book how, what we electrical engineers call "*maximum-length sequences*" (what you math guys call Galois fields, specifically in binary $GF(2)$) from Knuth.  i learned that a circular shifting of an MLS that is exclusive-OR'd against the unshifted sequence comes out to be the same circular sequence but shifted by some other wild and crazy amount.  we DSPers can use MLS as a function for measuring the impulse response of a discrete-time linear system.  but this $P(k)$ notation i hadn't seen.

Comment: and if i ever see $$ \sum\limits_{n=k}^{k-1} a_n$$ i'm gonna suspect that i am doing something wrong and look for my error.  because, it's hard for me to differentiate that from just summing it up in reverse order.  i'm gonna think it's the same as $$ \sum\limits_{n=k-1}^{k} a_n$$ and that ain't necessarily the same as 0.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Great. :-) I've studied many years ago besides math also computer science and Knuth was one of our gods due to his *Art of computer programming* and of course because he gave us $\TeX$.

Comment: ya know, Markus, it might not have been Knuth.  it might have been [this book by Golomb](https://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/9361).  but i **did** learn some stuff from Knuth.  i think i learned the fundamentals of a hash table and hashing from Knuth.